# jQuery Toggling width

Tags: jquery

Using the jQuery below I am trying to `.toggleClass` but also toggle the between 2 given widths. I can't quite figure out how to change between headerwidth and foabgwidth

```
$('.mChatOpts .pane').click(function(){
    var _headerwidth = $('#header').width();
    var _foabgwidth = $('.forabg').width();
    $('.chatbox').toggleClass('fixed',function(){           
        $('.fixed').css({
            'width':_headerwidth
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the element to see if it has the `fixed` class and act accordingly..

```
$('.mChatOpts .pane').click(function(){
    var _headerwidth = $('#header').width();
    var _foabgwidth = $('.forabg').width();
    $('.chatbox').toggleClass('fixed',function(){
        var self = $(this),
            added = self.hasClass('fixed'),
            widthToUse = _headerwidth; // initialise with one value

        if (added){
            widthToUse = _foabgwidth;
        }

        self.width(widthToUse);
    });
});
```

You should invert the `if (added)` if you want it the other way around..

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:

```
$('.mChatOpts .pane').click(function(){
var _headerwidth = $('#header').width();
var _foabgwidth = $('.forabg').width();
$('.fixed').css('width',_foabgwidth);
$('.chatbox').toggleClass('fixed',function(){           
    $('.fixed').css('width',_headerwidth);
});
});
```